# Set alarm from custom app in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Am new to android development. I developed my first app today. Now developing another one to understand it more.

My requirements are

1.) I will have two radio buttons, one is 10:00 AM and another one is 9:00 AM

2.) On clicking either 10:00 AM or 9:00 AM the alarm should set in my android default alarm service.

In google search, the examples are given only how to develop own alarm service (where we are setting alarm and receiving the same at specified time and playing the ring tone)

I dont want that. I just wanna use my app as another front end, which will schedule alarm in default clock-app of android.

Please suggest

Comment: I don't think that is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set an alarm for 10am:

```
Intent openClockIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
openClockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
openClockIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 10);
context.startActivity(openClockIntent);
```

You also need this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```